# Inform to the user when two users seeing the same task at same time

Tags: screensharing

I'm using spring-boot in my back-end and react-js in my front-end.

In my application I show a list of tasks when the user can click and open one task.

When the user has an open task, I need to inform if other user opened same task in real time, and if other user open the same task, I need to inform that exist two users seeing the same task. This is similar to Google docs when there is more than one user editing the same doc.

I was looking for on the internet but not found ideas about how to do this :(

Can someone help me to have some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in different ways.

For example every time a user opens a task you can save the task opened in your database. You can use an interval to check every 1 second if something changed, but it could become a poor performance way to accomplish this.

So another idea is to use websockets (see for example [React-Pusher](https://pusher.com/tutorials/react-websockets/) or even [this article](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-websocket-chat-example/) if you want to implement it with Java and Spring-Boot).

Comment: Perfect polo !!

I was thinking of websockets too.

My solution is to store the user and the tasks in redisdb when the user opens some task, and use the websockets to control the warnings when the user opens some task.

I think this solution meets all my needs.